# GETH syncmode=snap. Does it allow txpool / mempool / pending txs queries?

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm only interested in querying the mempool, and a full sync is projected to take more than 2 weeks. There isn't easily available documentation providing an answer to this question, or detailing the differences between a full and snap sync mode for my purpose. Any help or pointers to documentation would be greatly appreciated.